# How to update a variable after a loop using list comprehension

Tags: python, loops, printing

I have a code that print something like:

```
N, M = map(int,input().split())
x='.|.'
j=1
for i in range(N):
    print((x*j).center(M,'-'))
    j+=2
```

I have tried to shorten the code by using list comprehension:

```
[print((x*j).center(M,'-')) for i in range(N)]
```

How can I update the variable j for each loop? Thanks.

Comment: Don't do that. That is not what a list comprehension is for.

Comment: `print` returns None, so you're just building a list of null values, which is kinda wasteful.

Comment: Instead of trying to cram everything into one line, [read up on what the things you are using are capable of](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges). That would eliminate much more than swapping a loop for a mishandled comprehension.

Comment: "print comprehensive"? So now this abuse even has a name making it sound like something ok to do?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, it's very useful for a beginner like me :)

Answer (score 1):

I have worked around the problem using this:

```
[print((x*(1+i*2)).center(M,'-')) for i in range(N)]
```

This solution maybe short but I think it's not ideal for developing.